# Calling Pentaho Kettle job from BI Server using xaction

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-design-studio, xaction

My requirement is to call my kettle job from Pentaho BI server.
I am using 
Pentaho BI server 5.0.1 CE, 
PDI 4.3.0 - for kettle job and transformation design and 
PDS CE 4.0. - to design xaction that will call the kettle job

I have created an xaction and included the kettle job in the process actions of that xaction like,(Execute-->PDI job)
but iat first i got the below error

`"kettle error_0015 Could not load transformation job from resource [TANSNAME]"`

for that i have uploaded my kettle job with my xaction (as the BIServer5.0.1 maintains the solution file in jackrabbit) and referred my transformation URL as static in my job.
after that the job is executing, but the job arguments are not getting passed from my xaction. I have added the arguments in the XML source of the xaction. but still the pentaho log shows empty arguments.

Is there anything else i need to do?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest moving away from xactions. They are a quite old piece of the puzzle and I imagine they'll get deprecated soon.

As of now we have better tools, easier to understand, maintain and debug.

One such example is CDA as your data access plugin, which allows you to define a Kettle transformation as a data source. When calling the CDA dataAccess, the ktr is executed and the results of a specified step are sent back to the client issuing the query.

CDA is available through the Pentaho Marketplace

Comment: Thanks nsousa, but my requirement is to call the kettle job using BI server and xaction is the only way to do that(so far i have learned). also if we want to use kettle as a datasource, we can do it in Pentaho report itself no need CDA(if CDA provides more benefits than pentaho report).

Comment: Calling a CDA datasource is faster than rendering a report.